# onChange method not getting called from input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am having a button from which I open the file explorer. I am doing it like this

```
 {
   this.props.fileUploadIsOpen
      && <div className='assign-dialog'>
          <div className='assign-dialog-inner'>
             <div className='dia-title'> File Upload</div>
                <div className='dia-body'>
                   <div className='control-container'>
                       <div className='control-label'> Video File</div>
                           <div className='control'>
                             <input type="text" className="form-control" id="usr"/>
                             <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => this.upload.click()}>Browse</button>
                             <input id="myInput" type="file" ref={(ref) => this.upload = ref} style={{visibility: 'hidden', width:0}} onChange={this.handleFileSelect}/>
                           </div>
                       </div>
```

But onChange method is not getting called. When I select a file, nothing happens. onChange method is supposed to called handleFileSelect function, which prints the file name in console. But nothing happens in console. Is onChange not getting triggered? How can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe you should first separate your html, and your js code, because you are cluttering too much different code in your html. If you are using jquery you could do something similar to what in this[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vucaLn98/). As a side note, if you are generating the html on the fly, it is possible that your events are not being bound correctly. Test your functions with static code and see if they work.

Comment: letter c should be small while writing onchange={}

Comment: @komal `onChange` is an HTML attribute. HTML is case-insensitive. It's only when you are using the `onchange` element property in JavaScript that it should be all lower-case.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - thanks for your feedback but even in HTML, onchange is written with c in lower case. please check this link: http://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-onchange-attribute.php

Comment: @komal That is incorrect. All you are doing is pointing to a page that uses `onchange`. That page has to write it somehow, so they chose to write it in all lower-case. HTML is a case-insensitive language. Here's the documentation for that in the spec: http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html#case-insensitivity

Comment: @komal From the spec: *"Attribute names for HTML elements may be written with any mix of lowercase and uppercase letters that are a case-insensitive match for the names of the attributes given in the HTML elements section of this document; that is, attribute names are case-insensitive."*

Comment: It's irrelevant since this is using React (I added the tag for clarity), which rewrites the attributes anyway.

Comment: It's relevant in that an incorrect comment was posted and others in the future will read it.

Comment: Seems like I was not binding handleFileSelected. Solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why you are passing a function to the ref attr, but
I have recreated your case and it nails what you want

```
class Uploader extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    onClick (e) {
        const {fileUpload} = this.refs;
        fileUpload.click();
    }
    // prints the file name
    handleFileSelect (e) {
        const {fileUpload} = this.refs;
        console.log(fileUpload.files[0].name)
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='control-label'> Video File</div>
                <div className='control'>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="usr"/>
                    <button 
                    type="button" 
                    className="btn btn-primary" 
                    onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Browse</button>
                    <input id="myInput" type="file" ref="fileUpload" style={{visibility: 'hidden', width:0}} onChange={this.handleFileSelect.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't call handleFileSelect function here and it call by your eventListener, you need to bind it, like this code:

```
this.handleFileSelect.bind(this)
```